# Data frame incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to the R languange and I have an assignment where I should display a boxplot of data from an html table in wikipedia:

```
library("rvest")
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_oil_exports"
Countries <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[2]') %>% 
html_table(header=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
Countries <- Countries
head(Countries)
str(Countries)
for(i in 1:74){
     Countries[i,3] = as.numeric(Countries[i,3])
}
#ggplot(Oil_Exports) + geom_boxplot() +
#  ylab("Amount of oil Exports in (bbl/day)") +
#  opts(title = "List of countries by oil exports")
```

If I am moving correctly I am currently trying to change the values in column 3 for all rows to numeric (Oil - exports (bbl/day)). I get the following error:

```
List of 1
 $ :'data.frame':   74 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ Rank                   : int [1:74] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ Country/Region         : chr [1:74] "Saudi Arabia" "Russia" "Kuwait" "Iran" ...
  ..$ Oil - exports (bbl/day): chr [1:74] "6,880,000" "4,720,000" "2,750,000" "2,445,000" ...
  ..$ Date of
information   : chr [1:74] "2011 est." "2013 est." "2016 est." "2011 est." ...
  ..$ Oil - exports (bbl/day): chr [1:74] "8,865,000" "7,201,000" "2,300,000" "1,808,000" ...
  ..$ Date of
information   : int [1:74] 2012 2012 2012 2012 2016 2014 2012 2012 2012 2012 ...
Error in Countries[i, 3]: incorrect number of dimensions
Traceback:
```

How to solve the problem and if is there a better way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: your data.frame seems to be inside a list. Try `Countries[[1]][i, 3]`; also, you don't need a loop: `Countries[[1]][,3] <- as.numeric(Countries[[1]][,3])`

Comment: It seems to be working but I get this warining: Warning message in eval(expr, envir, enclos):
"NAs introduced by coercion"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of your scraping script is a list, not a data.frame. I think you want to extract only the data.frame that is the first object of this list. Thus, just add `Countries <- Countries[[1]]`

```
library("rvest")
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_oil_exports"
Countries <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[2]') %>% 
  html_table(header=TRUE, fill=TRUE)

Countries <- Countries[[1]]
```

However, this will not work out of the box since your variable contains comma separating thousands. Let's remove them:

```
Countries[,3] <- gsub(",", "", Countries[,3])
```

Moreover, you don't need a loop to transform a variable:

```
Countries[,3] <- as.numeric(Countries[,3])
Countries[,3]
```